# Increment Counter as part of TikZ Style

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters, tikz-styles

I would like to increment a counter every time a particular style is applied.  The MWE below compiles just fine, but the counter is not incremented.

[image]

I would like to have the counter value be 3 after the `tikzpicture`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\tikzset{My Style/.style={draw=red, .code={\stepcounter{MyCounter}}}}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{MyCounter}
BEFORE MyCounter=\the\value{MyCounter}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [My Style] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [My Style] (0,0) -- (3,2) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

AFTER MyCounter=\the\value{MyCounter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With `My Style/.style={draw=red, .code={\stepcounter{MyCounter}}}`, your style `My Style` defines an unused blank key linked to your code.

You may use :

```
\tikzset{My Style/.style={draw=red,inc/.code={\stepcounter{MyCounter}},inc}}
```

to define and use the `inc` key.

Or you may use `.code` handler instead of `.style` handler:

```
\tikzset{My Style/.code={\stepcounter{MyCounter}\tikzset{draw=red}}}
```

Or you may use the predefined key `/utils/exec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcounter{MyCounter}

\tikzset{My Style/.style={draw=red,/utils/exec={\stepcounter{MyCounter}}}}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{MyCounter}
BEFORE MyCounter=\the\value{MyCounter}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [My Style] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\draw [My Style] (0,0) -- (3,2) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

AFTER MyCounter=\the\value{MyCounter}
\end{document}
```

[image]